# MIcronaut-Jaxrs @RequestScope create only one object even with multiple requests

Tags: jax-rs, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I am trying to inject a io.micronaut.runtime.http.scope.RequestScope object into my jaxrs resource. Here I am priting object to see if it creates different objects for each request. But the object created Only once, even when I sent multiple requests.
Is this a known issue ? Any other way to work around this if that's the case.

```
@RequestScope
public class RequestScopeObjectX {

    public RequestScopeObjectX() {
        System.out.println("-------------------------"+this);
    }
}
```

And in. my jaxrs resource class I am doing injecting it

```
@Inject
RequestScopeObjectX objectX;
```

Comment: Too little code to tell, but how many times is the constructor for the class that is hosting the injected instance called? Might be related to this issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1615

Comment: This is working as expected. Only I was testing in incorrect way. Like checking injected object hash code to be different. Turns out that’s a proxy being injected and read object is actually creating for every request.